# How to display a list of days including days without any logged activities in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have made a google form in which I input how much I train and meditate each day and I would like to make a summary of that data so that I can easily how much I have done each day INCLUDING the days where I have done nothing.

I have a working solution but it involves me adding all empty days manually to be able to show them in my summary/status.

Current solution:

1. Sheet 1: "**Form responses 1**" - This is where all the data comes in
2. Sheet 2: "**DatesTraning**" - This is a list of all days and a 0 (zero) for each day in the column listing how many minutes I have been training. The columns in this manually created sheet is identical to the ones in "Form responses 1"
3. Sheet 3: "**ResponsesAndDates**" - This where I combine the data from "Form responses 1" and "DatesTraining" with the following query:

```
=query({'Form responses 1'!A2:M;DatesTraning!A1:M},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where (Col1 < date '"&TEXT(TODAY() +1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') order by Col1 desc")
```

4. Sheet 4: "**Status**" - This is where I summarize/display things with forumulas like this:

```
=query(ResponsesAndDates!A1:M,"select toDate(K),sum(H) where C='Träna' group by toDate(K) order by toDate(K) desc label toDate(K) 'Datum', sum(H) 'Total tid'")
```

Column C is a category column (so I can add filtering for more categories of entries)
Column H contains the number of minutes trained
Column K contains the date for the training/meditation

I did this to be able to easily see both the days where things are logged in addition to the days where things have not been logged. Is there a more easy way to do this without the manual step of using the "*DatesTraining*" sheet?

Comment: Would an apps script solution be acceptable?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @rafaguillermo A script would be ok sure. I'm just trying to find a solution which limits the information I manually have to enter

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?